# como determinar numero de semana en un mes dada una fecha

Tags: php

Buenas tardes estoy programando la siguiente función para que me devuelva la fecha del primer domingo de un mes dado, la función es la siguiente:

```
fecha1 = new Date("2017-09-03");
diapararestar=fecha1.getUTCDay();
if(diapararestar==0){
    dia1=(-6);        
}else{
    dia1=(diapararestar-1)*(-1);        
}

fecha1.setDate(fecha1.getDate() + dias1);
```

pero me devuelve este formato de fecha: `"2017-08-28T00:00:00.000Z"` pero realmente estoy interesado en que me devuelva la fecha de la siguiente manera `2017-08-28`, que puedo corregir para solucionar esto

Comment: Eso es PHP?.....

Comment: Deberías editar y agregar la etiqueta del lenguaje que estás usando por que de lo contrario las respuestas no serán del todo acertadas

Comment: tiene usted razon copie mal el algoritmo. enseguida lo edito